# How to escape forEach returning true or false

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase-realtime-database

I need to make this code works:

```
router.post('/checkProduct',function(req,res) {
  ref.child("recipts").once("value",function(usersSnap) {
  var purchasedval = "";
    usersSnap.forEach(function (reciptsSnap) { //for every user
      if(reciptsSnap.key === req.body.userId) {
        reciptsSnap.forEach(function (reciptSnap) {
          reciptSnap.ref.child("latest_receipt_info").once("value",function(b) {
            purchasedval = "false";
            b.forEach(function (c) {
              if(c.val().product_id === req.body.productId && reciptSnap.val().status === "on") {
                purchasedval = "true";
              }
            });
          });
        });
      }
    });
    return res.send({ "alreadyPurchased" : purchasedval })
  });
});
```

The if part actually is accomplished but it returns "". If I make the return inside the if, it would say the issue about setting many time the headers, so this is why I create a variable like purchasedval but I don't know how to set it after the forEachs finish. Any idea?

Comment: Are you sure that the `if` block statements run once?

Comment: It could enter inside the if many times,  I need to return true if it enters there

Comment: You can call  `res.send`  just one time for a `request`. Do you want this?

Comment: I know it could be called just once.... I need that if it enters the IF even just once returns true... if the code never enters the if returns false... any idea @saeid ?

Comment: You can break out of a [Firebase Snapshot's `forEach`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#forEach) by returning `true`, but that won't help you unless you restructure the code, as you are making an asynchronous call to `once` within the inner loop - that's why `purchasedval` is `""`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this for your `if` block:

```js
...
// when you define purchaseval
var perchaseval = false;
var send = false;
...
if(!purchasedval && c.val().product_id === req.body.productId && reciptSnap.val().status === "on") {
  purchasedval = "true";
  send = true;
  res.send({ "alreadyPurchased" : purchasedval });
 }
else if(!send) {
  send = true;
  res.send({ "alreadyPurchased" : purchasedval });
 }
```

If you want to skip `forEach` after `res.send` you can use `Array.prototype.every` and inside your `if` you can use `break`.
But my best offer is using a module like `Async` or `Promises` paradigm

Comment: So I got.. FIREBASE WARNING: Exception was thrown by user callback. Error: Can't set headers after they are sent. and... wrong result ... it should be true I think I need to restructure the code

Comment: do you know how could be the implementation with async?

Comment: I ended up declaring this on a variable for anyone interested

Answer (score 0):

You can't break out of forEach. You need to use a normal for loop.

Comment: looping through many for loops is such a nasty thing in firebase... :(

Comment: What does this have to do with Firebase?

Comment: validate that two values for two parameters exist for an ID. If both values exists return true, if not false